# URL parameters for GET request

Tags: python, python-requests

i have to make a make with get parameter "scope" "scope:priavte scope"

using requets module of python

Note values of **scope** parameter has to space separated.

```
url_1 = "https://www.testapp.com/oauth/authorize/"
payload = {"scope": "scope:private scope:public", "client_id"=xxx}

>> req = requests.get(url_1, params=payload)
>> url
>>https://www.testapp.com/oauth/authorize/?scope=scope%3Aprivate+scope%3Apublic&client_id=XXX
>> req.status_code
400
```

whereas this url works

```
 url_2 = "https://www.testapp.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxx&scope=scope:public%20scope:private"
>> req = requests.get(url_2)
>> req.status_code
200
```

the differnce between the two urls is of how the **scope** get parameter value `"scope:private scope:public"`  is encoded.

url_1 uses `%3A for : and + for space`

while url_2 uses `: is not encoded and %20 for space`

How to make request with  `url_1` successful ?

Comment: Check the server if it understands URL encoded params.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a clever way to do it... I thought perhaps something with request hooks, but it seems that one can't hook into the request.

You can, however, do it manually using `urllib.quote()` specifying `:` as a safe character and then passing it to `requests.get()` as a string:

```
import urllib
import requests

payload = {"scope": "scope:private scope:public", "client_id": "xxx"}
query_string = '&'.join(['='.join((k, urllib.quote(v, ':'))) for k,v in payload.items()])
req = requests.get(url_1, params=query_string)
```

The resulting query string looks like this:

```
>>> print query_string
scope=scope:private%20scope:public&client_id=xxx
```